# How do I disable IntelliJ IDEA's type inspection?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA's Scala plugin many times complains about "type mismatch" even though the code in question compiles absolutely fine. I find this quite irritating, and would like to disable this feature. I didn't find any relevant option on searching in the settings. How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 10):

Switching off 'Type Aware Highlighting' by clicking this symbol may help a bit.

[image]

Edit

There are also a number of Scala specific inspections which can be enabled and disabled. These can be accessed by clicking on the 'Inspector' icon (just to the left of the 'Type Aware' icon) shown in the first screenshot above and clicking 'configure inspections on the pop-up dialog.

[image]

Comment: Oh well ... sounds like a wait for the next plugin version.

Answer (score 4):

You can completely turn off error highlighting by clicking the little man with a bowler hat at the bottom-right hand corner of the screen and choosing "None" for Highlighting Level. But then you lose all error highlighting, not just the one that is annoying you. (Sorry, StackOverflow won't let me post an image to show exactly where to find "Hector the Inspector!)

Comment: Thanks, but moving that bar to None turns off syntax highlighting too.

Comment: If you have got a small test case I suggest you file a bug (or post it here), I have always found JetBrains quite reactive.

Comment: Since code won't look good in comments, I am posting it as a separate answer.

Comment: @missingfaktor Do you have a self-contained example (just using API from the Scala libraries)? Your example is nice and small but hard to post as a bug due to the external dependencies.

Comment: Sorry, that's hard. The information provided with the example appears to be good enough for IDEA guys to figure out and hopefully fix the problem.

Answer (score 4):

There seems a way to disable type aware highlighting just for a region of Scala code in IntelliJ. This was mentioned by a JetBrains developer in [SCL-10983](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-10983), later I found a documentation in [Troubleshoot common Scala issues](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/troubleshoot-common-scala-issues.html).

Let us take following code (intentionally plain wrong):

```
class Data {
  /*_*/
  def data: Int = this
  /*_*/
  def dataAgain: Int = this
}
```

Only the second error will be highlighted in red, the first one enclosed in `/*_*/` will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

@rxg: Here is a small test case to demonstrate the problem:

`rows` is of type `IndexedSeq[Row]` where `Row` is from Apache POI's Excel library. `traverse` if a function from Scalaz. `Validation` is a data structure from Scalaz.
`GryphonError` is an ADT from our codebase.

```
rows.zipWithIndex.traverse[({type L[X] = Validation[Seq[GryphonError], X]})#L, Seq[Any]] { case (row, r) =>
  // some stuff
}
```

scalac compiles this code fine.
IDEA's type-inspector complains:

```
   Type mismatch, expected: ((Row, Int) => F[B])
                  actual:   ((Row, Int) => F[IndexedSeq[B]])
```