# IntelliJ mistakenly highlights "Wrong number of arguments for extractor"

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Matching case class with TuppleN parameter i get such highlighting
"Wrong number of arguments for extractor"... Of course such code compiles and executes perfectly well

Simple example

```
case class SomeTestClass(param: (String, String))
val t = SomeTestClass("love" -> "life")
t match {
  // here i get highlighting "wrong number arguments for extractor"
  case SomeTestClass(Tuple2(param1, param2)) => true
  case _ => false
}
```

the same story for

```
case SomeTestClass((param1, param2)) => true
case SomeTestClass(param) => true
```

How to get rid of this? It seems like it was not before, and i didnt upgrade IDE

UPD: Disabling Type control is not a good idea as it is very very helpful, using /*_*/ folding construction works but it is just replacing one trouble to another, so not seems too much attractive

Comment: May be somewhere in settings i can turn off this particular type of highlighting?

Comment: Getting rid of the error is easy. Press the little green `[T]`  in the bottom right corner of the IDE to disable type-aware highlighting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Controlling false IntelliJ code editor error in Scala plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36679973/controlling-false-intellij-code-editor-error-in-scala-plugin)

Comment: jrook, not really, type control is very very helpful, i hoped that i can disable just this particular type of control "Wrong number of arguments for extractor"

Comment: Please edit your question making it clear for everyone that you have seen the other alternative and it is not suitable for your case. It is impossible to distinguish that the linked question wouldn't work for your case from the content of your question.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the best solution for that problem, but you can enclose wrongly highlighted fragment of code with `/*_*/` and disable highlighting in that particular part of code.

This looks like a bug and the best place to tell about it is the IDEA bug-tracker. There are many places where intelliJ highlighter could disagree with scalac.

Anyway, you can avoid this by unfolding your tuple into named variables.

Comment: Yes, /*_*/ works, but it is not better, instead of one type of unnecessery highlighting i should put another one but now myself. Unfolding tuple into named variables inside match case expression doesnt help, but if you mean to replace tuple inside case class definition then it is not good for code in my case. I'd better tolerate this stupid highlighting rather than change my code

Comment: No reason to tolerate - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL, share this bug and eventually it will be fixed. JetBrains does not ignore these for too long.

Comment: It looks like Andrey Sugak beat you to it. See the previous issue. +1 here for creative test data and the extreme irony of "i should put another one." Even with "correct" linting, there might be a mechanism to "signal no lint here"; for example, annotating `expr: Unit` to say "OK to discard this value." I'd rather treat the lint message like email, mark it read. Maybe someday it's no longer safe to discard result of expr, I'd like it to force me to re-read the lints on a clean build (or after git clean).